# Is it okay if ASAN runtime loaded as second library?

Tags: address-sanitizer

I want to use ASAN for a process on a system. The system requires another library libfoo to be loaded first. libfoo does not intercept any allocations.

```
ldd asan_instrumented_proc
    1. linux-vdso.so.1
    2. libfoo
    3. libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so
```

I made changes to ASAN to ignore the check on if ASAN is the first linked library.

Do you see any issues with this usage , provided that libfoo does not interfere in asan's functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work as long as as `libfoo` does not intercept any function already intercepted by Asan (you can get full list from `readelf -sW --dyn-syms $(gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so)`). To be safe Asan will emit a warning in that case which you can suppress via `ASAN_OPTIONS=verify_asan_link_order=0`.